# Can't seem to Import Class Properly (org.joda.time)

Tags: java, import

I am new to java. I am trying to import a class:
import org.joda.time.*;

This no longer is giving me an issue but I can't seem to use the methods exposed in the class:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
```

> "DateTime cannot be resolved to a type"

My project structure is simple:

```
Name "AssignmentOne"
Two classes: Students, StudentCalc
```

StudentCalc contains the import statement and where I try and declare the object. Students is where my main is.

Comment: You need the JAR which provides Joda. Are you using Maven or any other dependency management?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669694/eclipse-not-finding-classes-added-to-the-build-path-java-dynamic-web-project

This was my answer.